# Set-AuthenticodeSignature: does it support OfficeSIPS?

Tags: powershell, code-signing

I followed this guide to sign office macros, and succeeded by using "signtool.exe": https://docs.digicert.com/en/digicert-keylocker/signing-tools/excel-macro-signing-with-signtool.html
So I assume I registered the OfficeSIPS dlls properly, and everything is fine with the certificate.

Then I stumbled over the powershell command "Set-AuthenticodeSignature", which should also support SIPS format (quote from the doc: "The Set-AuthenticodeSignature cmdlet adds an Authenticode signature to any file that supports Subject Interface Package (SIP)."). I can use it to sign ps1 files or a .NET exe file.

But I run into error messages when using it for a .docm file. The call fails with "Unknown" error and a meaningless status message "*Das für den Antragsteller angegebene Formular wird vom angegebenen Vertrauensanbieter nicht unterstützt oder ist ihm nicht bekannt*" - according to Google, this is "*The form specified for the subject is not one supported or known by the specified trust provider.*".

This error also appears if I sign the docm with "signtool.exe", then try to validate the signature with the command "Get-AuthenticodeSignature".

Does anyone have an idea whether the powershell command supports signing office macros?

I could stay with signtool, but I am curious whether it is possible with Powershell. At least, it would be easier to parse the result of a powershell command ;-)

This is the powershell snippet that I use to sign:

```
$certFound=Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\CurrentUser\My -CodeSigningCert
Set-AuthenticodeSignature -Certificate $CertFound -TimestampServer "http://timestamp.digicert.com" -HashAlgorithm SHA256 -FilePath '.\MyFile.ps1'
```

It works for "ps1" files, but fails for a word macro file.

Comment: I made some progress: it works if I use the x86 powershell version, but it fails with x64 - probably because the OfficeSIPS dlls are x86.

Answer (score 0):

But when evaluating the result of the sign call, the result is in "error" state:

```
$certFound=Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\CurrentUser\My -CodeSigningCert
[System.Management.Automation.Signature] $SignResult = Set-AuthenticodeSignature -Certificate $CertFound -TimestampServer "http://timestamp.digicert.com" -HashAlgorithm SHA256 -FilePath '.\MyFile.ps1
```

Here, "$SignResult.Status" is "UnknownError" with the message "Unknown error (0x80072efd)".

The office file has signed macros now, as can evaluated in the macro editor and by calling "Get-AuthenticodeSignature".

Comment: Posted it in the powershell 7 github and will keep this updated: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/20903